# Firth's Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to find predictors for people selling their cars by doing a logistic regression. My sample size is n=922 and has mostly kardinal and ordinal variables. 
Since some of my variables have up to 7 categories (--> 6 dummyvariables) I came across separation. 
In the literature they recommend the bias-reduced logistic regression approach of Firth.

After installing the package I used the following formula:

`logistf(formula = attr(data, "formula"), data = sys.parent(), pl = TRUE, ...)`

and entered (or tried to enter) my data:

```
mydataBrAll <- logistf(formula = attr(mydataBr$Verkauft, "formula"), data = mydataBr, pl = FALSE)
summary(mydataBrAll)
```

*Verkauft* being my dependent variable and *mydataBr* being my data

What kind of term has to be entered in *"formula"* ? 
And if this works, can I use the stepwise backwards algorithm (or the pseudo R² etc) the same way as I'd use it in a regular log.reg. model?:

```
'Backwards Selection'
backwards <- step(mydataBrAll, direction = "backward")
```

Some of you might consider this as an easy problem, but I can't figure it out with the help of the explanations online.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should be a regular formula object used in most modeling functions in R (like `lm()`, `glm()`, etc.).
You can get details on how to write a formula by typing `help(formula)` in an R command line.

Essentially a formula is an expression of the form `y ~ model`. Quoting from the details section of `help(formula)`:

> An expression of the form y ~ model is interpreted as a specification that the response y is modelled by a linear predictor specified symbolically by model.

In your example, assuming you had 3 predictors called `x1`, `x2`, `x3` (which could be either `numeric` or `factor` variables), you could write:

```
mydataBrAll <- logistf(formula = Verkauft ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = mydataBr, pl = FALSE)
summary(mydataBrAll)
```

Note that the formula could be more complicated and involve transformations of the predictor variables. Again, for more details see the documentation of `formula`.

Just so you know, the `attr(data, "formula")` expression shown in the documentation of `logistf()` as part of the function signature (a.k.a. API) refers to the attribute called `formula` that might exist in the object containing the data you are passsing in the `data` parameter of the function. Since this is not the case in your example (as clearly you haven't added that attribute to your data object), you must explicitly define the formula when calling `logistf()`.
For more information about attributes in objects, see `help(attr)`.

For your second question about backward selection: in the Details section of the documentation for `logistf()` you see the following sentence:

> Furthermore, forward and backward functions perform convenient variable selection

I.e. the package contains a `forward()` and `backward()` function that can be used to perform forward and backward selection of predictors.

The `step()` function might also work, as nothing indicates the contrary in its documentation page.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply!

In fact I already tried the approach that you suggested:

```mydataBrAll <- logistf(formula = Verkauft ~ ., data = mydataBr, pl = FALSE)```

But unfortunately the calculation takes too long so that I never get a result and have to terminate the R session.

I even tried it with less independent variables to see if the model size causes the problem.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Without looking at the data it's difficult to tell what the problem is. My initial guess is that you may have variables with too many categories...? I would suggest you try fitting separate regressions, each with just one predictor at a time and see which one generates the problem.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you!
I saw that one of my variables has a category with no entries. After reducing that category it worked. Unfortunately when I tried to use the step() function afterwards, I got this error message:
``` Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors```
After checking with the function is.atomic() I saw that 
```mydataBrAll$Alter``` is indeed atomic. Do you know how to change that in order to be able to use the backwards algorithm.

If you need to know more about my data I can post at least the variables and comment on the data they're based on.

Comment: Well, actually the problem should be another. The error message tells you that the **operator `$`** is invalid for atomic vectors, which means that the `step()` function is trying to apply the `$` operator to a vector (BTW "atomic vector" is the same as saying "vector" --see here: http://arrgh.tim-smith.us/atomic.html). So, no surprise that `mydataBrAll$Alter` is an atomic vector as every column of a data frame is an atomic vector. As I said, the reason behind the error should be find elsewhere (analyzing what the `step()` function does).

Comment: Have you tried applying the `backward()` function that comes with the `logistf` package?

Comment: Yes...but using the backward() function I also get an error message:
```backward(mydataBrAll)``` (putting everything else on default)
leads to:
```'.' in formula and no 'data' argument```

Comment: The error most likely means that the `backward()` function doesn't know with which variables it should start the backward selection process, because: (i) you used `.` for the RHS of your formula when running `logistf()`, and (ii) you did not specify a `data=` argument in the `backward()` call (note that `backward()` accepts additional parameters (not explicitly listed in the signature) in the `...` argument). So try either: (i) calling `logistf()` by explicitly listing all initial variables, or calling `backward(mydataBrAll, data=mydataBr)`. See also the examples of `backward()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It finally worked out! 
The results seem to be reasonable. 
I'm only wondering why the significance (the p value) of some of the variables are slightly different when using the forward() or backward() approach.

Comment: I am glad it worked out! Regarding the p-values: normally the variables selected using the backward vs. forward selection *are* different... Did you obtain exactly the same selected variables in both approaches?